# How to link html folders using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble understanding Javascript and I have a task to link a webpage within my  website I created to another using Javascript and I am not sure how to!
Is this how I should start?

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").
```

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use documentwriteln for this if I understood your question well and if not can you elaborate your question better as I didn't completely get what do you mean.

```
document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='Script1.js'></script>");
```

Comment: i need a create a hyperlink within my webpage using javascript! :)

Comment: You can use ahref for that,